# Unable to publish Citrix Xenapp over Internet (WAN)

Tags: citrix, xenapp

I have installed a xenapp server which is working fine in a local environment but when it comes to publish application over WAN it says

Could not connect to server

however its opening the webpage for citrix signin and I am able to sign in & can see all the published apps, but when I click any of them it downloads. ica application file and the gives the error.

Note: I have installed certificate and citrix receiver, I have done port mapping on router that's why I am able to open the citrix login page..

Answer (score 0):

Have you also opened up the required ICA ports to the servers in your farm?

Depending on how you have things configured, you will also need to open ports TCP/1494 and/or TCP/2598 to your server farm or from your secure gateway device (or netscaler) to your XenApp application servers.

Comment: Yes I had done that as well, I also tried without firewall on. Did not work in both the cases..